# "BETWEEN" SQL Keyword for Oracle Dates -- Getting an error in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have dates in this format in my database "01-APR-12" and the column is a DATE type.

My SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerno, c.lname, c.fname
FROM customer c, sales s
WHERE c.customerno = s.customerno AND s.salestype = 1 
AND (s.salesdate BETWEEN '01-APR-12' AND '31-APR-12');
```

When I try to do it that way, I get this error -- ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified.

Can I even use the BETWEEN keyword with how the date is setup in the database?

If not, is there another way I can get the output of data that is in that date range without having to fix the data in the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

April has 30 days not 31.

Change

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerno, c.lname, c.fname
FROM customer c, sales s
WHERE c.customerno = s.customerno AND s.salestype = 1 
AND (s.salesdate BETWEEN '01-APR-12' AND '31-APR-12');
```

to

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerno, c.lname, c.fname
FROM customer c, sales s
WHERE c.customerno = s.customerno AND s.salestype = 1 
AND (s.salesdate BETWEEN '01-APR-12' AND '30-APR-12');
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: It amazes me that I could do something SO stupid...Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's cool - I don't think there's a programmer alive who hasn't made such a simple error; Think of it as an indicator that it's a good time to walk away from your computer for a bit and get some fresh air! Don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the tick :)

Answer (score 1):

In case the dates you are checking for range from 1st day of a month to the last day of a month then you may modify the query to avoid the case where you have to explicitly check the LAST day of the month

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerno, c.lname, c.fname
  FROM customer c, sales s
 WHERE c.customerno = s.customerno
   AND s.salestype = 1 AND (s.salesdate BETWEEN '01-APR-12' AND LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('APR-12', 'MON-YY'));
```

The LAST_DAY function will provide the last day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are missing out on something important and will not return the correct results.  Dates have date and time components.  If your salesdate column is in fact a date that includes time, you will miss out on any sales that happened on April 30 unless they occurred exactly at midnight.

Here's an example:

```
create table date_temp  (temp date);
insert into date_temp values(to_date('01-APR-2014 15:12:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
insert into date_temp values(to_date('30-APR-2014 15:12:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

table DATE_TEMP created.

1 rows inserted.

1 rows inserted.

```
select * from date_temp where temp between '01-APR-2014' and '30-APR-2014';
```

Query Result:  01-APR-14

If you want to get all records from April that includes those with time-components in the date fields, you should use the first day of the next month as the second side of the between clause:

```
select * from date_temp where temp between '01-APR-2014' and '01-MAY-2014';
```

01-APR-14

30-APR-14